# Terraform issue in deleting server parameter Postgresql flexi server

Tags: postgresql, azure, terraform, destroy, pgbouncer

Getting error:waiting for deletion of Flexible Server Configuration (pgbouncer.enabled)
Once I change the configuration from portal the script works.

```
azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_configuration" "pgbouncer" 
{ name = "pgbouncer.enabled" 
value = var.pgbouncer 
server_id = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.pgsql.id
 }
```

Comment: Nope, you will have to add a lot more details if you want any help.

Comment: I am adding resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_configuration" "pgbouncer" {
  name      = "pgbouncer.enabled"
  value     = var.pgbouncer
  server_id = azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.pgsql.id

} in my server creation while destroying i am getting error as Error: waiting for deletion of Flexible Server Configuration: (Configuration Name "pgbouncer.enabled" / Flexible Server Name "): Code="InternalServerError" Message="An unexpected error occured while processing the request. Tracking ID: ''"

Comment: Please add that code to the question.

Comment: Marko-Updated the code server configuration code i have used.After turning pgbouncer false in portal,i am able to destroy using terraform but before that i am getting the above error